# How to pass Query Variables

Tags: spring-boot, graphql

I am using spring boot graphQL application. My Query looks like below

```
query employeeInfo($empId: Int = 5) {
  employee(id: $empId) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

As you see above snippet, I defined $empId variable and initialize it with value 5.

When I hit GraphQL API, I observed below message in console.

```
{"query":"query employeeInfo($empId: Int = 5) {\n  employee(id: $empId) {\n    firstName\n    lastName\n  }\n}\n","variables":null,"operationName":"employeeInfo"}]
```

As you see the above snippet, variables section has null value.

How can I pass the query variables in spring graphqli?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can able to resolve this with below query payload.

```
query employeeInfo($empId: Int!) {
  employee(id: $empId) {
    firstName
    lastName
  }
}
```

Passed below snippet in Query Variables section.

```
{
  "empId" : 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set a default value to an argument like this:

```
type employeeInfo {
   firstName: String
   lastName: String
   empId: Int = 5
}
```